# Get the HTML content of a template Meteor

Tags: meteor

How do I get the html content of a template? For example, I have the following template:

```
<template name="test">
<div id="example">
    <strong>This is a test.</strong>
</div> <button id="btn">Get</button></template>
```

I need the event click of button the HTML contents of the div # example is captured. it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (already built into meteor) for this

```
var html = $('#example').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Meteor 1.x, you can use [Blaze.toHTML()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtml). It returns the HTML of the given Template as a String.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the click event using Template.test.events you should have all the data that template describess in your "this".